# Mvvmcross with Android, ItemClick does not launch the second ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I couldn't figure out what I have done wrong on this, I followed the tutorial (https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-16-CollectABull-Part5/CollectABull.Core/ViewModels/ListViewModel.cs) on how to bind a list and pull up a detail screen when a particular list item is selected.  My problem is when an item is selected, nothing happens.  I am using fluent binding to handle the data bind since I am hoping to utilize abstract activiies/view models.  Some code snippets are as follows:

My list layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/project"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Mvx.MvxListView android:id="@+id/List"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
               local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/list_item"
           />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
public class List : AbstractList {

    public new ListView ViewModel{
        get { return (ListView) base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<List, ListView>();
        set.Bind(list).For(x => x.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.List);
        set.Bind(list).For(x => x.ItemClick).To(vm => vm.ShowDetail);
        set.Apply();

    }
}
```

My Abstract Activity:

```
 public class AbstractList : MvxActivity{

    protected Legacy.LegacyBar actionBar;
    protected MvxListView list;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.list);

        actionBar = FindViewById<Legacy.LegacyBar>(Resource.Id.actionbar);
        list = FindViewById<MvxListView>(Resource.Id.List);

        actionBar.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center);
        actionBar.Title = Title;
    }
}
```

My View Model:

```
public class ListView : AbstractListView<Item>{

    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public ListView(IRepository repo){
        repository= repo;
        DataBind();
    }

    public List<Item> List{
        get { return list; }
        set{
            list = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => List);
        }
    }

    protected override Task<QueryResult<Item>> DataBindCall(){
        return repository.Get(new Query());
    }

    protected override void SetResultList(Item[] resultList){
        List = resultList.ToList();
    }
}
```

My Abstract View Model:

```
public abstract class AbstractListView<T> : MvxViewModel where T: class, new (){

    protected List<T> list;

    public IMvxCommand ShowDetail {
        get {
            return new MvxCommand<Item>(item => ShowViewModel<ItemView>(new ItemView.Navigation() { Id = item.ID }));
        }
    }

    protected abstract Task<QueryResult<T>> DataBindCall();
    protected abstract void SetResultList(T[] resultList);

    protected void DataBind(){
       DataBindCall().ContinueWith(x => {
            SetResultList(x.Result.Results);
        });
    }        
}
```

When I step through the code, I can see that it breaks on ShowDetail at the binding calls, however, after the list is loaded and I click on one of the items of the list, it does nothing.  It looks to me like the bind is unsuccessful, but there's no error message or anything from logcat.  I've also tried pulling up my detail page manually, and it's loading correctly, so there's no issue with the detail page itself.  Am I confusing the binding mechanism with all the abstract classes I introduced?  Or are there some very obvious mistakes that I couldn't see.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: does removing the xml template (using default) and/or removing the choicemode change anything? if you put some kind of trace in place of "ShowViewModel<ItemView>" does that trace get called?

Comment: Thank you Stuart for your quick response!  It's the template that's causing the issue.  A quick question, if I use fluent binding for one property, does that mean I need to use fluent binding for everything (including the template)?

Comment: Thank you @Stuart for pointing me to the cause of the issue.  My list item template is to blame and the property that is the root is the android:clickable property on root layout of the item.  Once I remove that, the item click and detail view is loading correctly.